# How to handle Makefiles to merge two separate programs

Tags: c

I am trying to use:

http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Nfc-eventd
and
https://code.google.com/p/libfreefare/

to create a new program that make use of code from both of these.

I have started with copy and pasting code from `mifare-classic-read-ndef.c` (from libfreefare) to `nfc-eventd.c` and when I run **`make`** I get the expected errors:

```
...
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src'
  CCLD   nfc-eventd
nfc-eventd.o: In function `main':
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:380: undefined reference to `freefare_get_tags'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:387: undefined reference to `freefare_get_tag_type'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:395: undefined reference to `freefare_get_tag_uid'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:398: undefined reference to `freefare_get_tag_friendly_name'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:407: undefined reference to `mifare_classic_connect'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:470: undefined reference to `freefare_free_tags'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:414: undefined reference to `mad_read'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:418: undefined reference to `mad_nfcforum_aid'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:418: undefined reference to `mifare_classic_nfcforum_public_key_a'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:418: undefined reference to `mifare_application_read'
/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src/nfc-eventd.c:422: undefined reference to `tlv_decode'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [nfc-eventd] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kapcom01/temp/nfc-eventd'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Obviously I have to link somehow the `freefare.h` and all the other source files of libreefare but I cant figure out how..

Just `#include "freefare.h"` and copy-paste the files into the same directory didn't work.

Comment: Seems like this belongs in StackOverflow. I flagged it for mod attention as I don't have merge power.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-lfreefare` to your link line?

Comment: Thanks that worked. I added -lfreefare at the AM_CFLAGS line in nfc-eventd/src/Makefile.am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use an NFC library by copying pieces of the library code directly into your program? I don't see how that could work. What you need to do is (a) build the library or download a precompiled version for your platform, (b) read the documentation regarding the API the library offers, and use that API in your code, and (c) when compiling your program, link with the library, possibly by adding `-lfreefare` or something similar to the link line in your Makefile. (The library's documentation should probably tell you how to do this as well.)

Comment: Thanks that worked. I added -lfreefare at the AM_CFLAGS line in nfc-eventd/src/Makefile.am